# Search weighting algorithm

Tags: algorithms

I am trying to devise a weighting algorithm that takes into account 4 factors in a specific order, with specific orders in those orders. To order a set of search results from a database.

So the setup is as follows,

```
v = integer between 1 and 8 (first and most important criteria, lower better)  
p = is a decimal between 0.00 and n produced using (price - offer price) (bigger is better)   
t = integer between 1 and 5  (lower is better)
b = integer between 4 and 120 (bigger is better)
```

I cannot seem to make an equation which includes the the priorities in the right order, or get around the fact that `c` and `p` 1 is a more positive weight than 3 etc.

So far I have tried

$ \dfrac{pb}{tv} $

This doesn't work as it can produce a `0`

$ \dfrac{pb-v}{t} $

Can work as you'll get a negative number, but doesn't take into account the weight priorities.

The last one I tried was this, to try and avoid producing a `0`

$ \dfrac{bv}{p+t} $

Comment: Is there an upper bound on $n$?

Comment: @JohnHabert In the data I'm working with it seems to be between `0.00` and `54.45`, I can't imagine a price with an offer being more than `100.00` though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try $a_4(9-v)^4+a_3p^3+a_2(6-t)^2+a_1b+a_0$ where the $a_i$ are some coefficients you pick to make the weighting turn out like you want it too. Most likely you'll end up with $a_0=0$ since this function will never be $0$ so no need to shift up. Since the range for $p$ is large compared to the range for $v$, $a_4$ will need to be quite a bit bigger than $a_3$ to compensate.

Comment: Thanks! I will give this a try

Comment: Looks to be working great, really appreciate the help.